# How to take sum using group by in Scala?

Tags: scala, group-by

I am new to Scala programming.

My original data set

```
recent, freq, monitor
1 3000 29299
2 3001 30100
5 3008 30120
6 3004 30110
9 3043 30130
```

Below is the data set which I generated from original data set

```
val ind = 
    ((1,3),0)
    ((2,3),1)
    ((5,2),2)
    ((6,2),3)
    ((9,1),4)
    ((3000,3),0)
    ((3001,3),1)
    ((3004,2),2)
    ((3008,1),3)
    ((3043,1),4)
    ((29299,3),0)
    ((30100,3),1)
    ((30110,2),2)
    ((30120,1),3)
    ((30130,1),4)
```

Now i want to groupby on index values and take the sum on second value with additional operations.

My index values are 0,1,2,3,4 (extreme right)
My sum values are the second column

```
For instance

(1,3),0) ((3000,3),0) ((29299,3),0)  => (3 * 100) + (3 * 10) + 3 = 333

((2,3),1) ((3001,3),1) ((30100,3),1) => ( 1* 10) + ( 1 * 10) + 1 = 111
```

Below is the code which I am using to calculate the sum but couldn't get the desired output

```
ind.groupBy(_._2).map(x => x._2.map(y => y._1.map(z => println(z._1,z._2,(z._2.toInt) * 100 + (z._2.toInt)* 10 + z._2.toInt))))
```

Data type is ((String, String), Int) after applying group by

```
ind.groupBy(_._2)     _._2 => (String, String), Int)
```

So My Final output should be like this. Here is column named Score I want to calculate using group by

```
recent freq monitor Score 
    1  3000 29299   333
    2  3001 30100   333
    5  3008 30120   222
    6  3004 30110   222 
    9  3043 30130   111
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the value of `ind` in a format that we can copy and paste instead of trying to guess what its content is.

Comment: @Dogbert  Its in the same format which I am getting.I already put in the question.

Comment: @Dogbert It would be helpful if you just give me the similar example of sum using groupby. I did try to find but I couldn't get it.

Comment: Relying on ordering of the values in the list in order to determine the meaning of a value is generally a really bad idea, your code ends up horribly brittle. If instead you can build a case class to represent the rows in your original dataset, along with their respective scores you'll have a far easier time calculating the total.